# problem with saving table data to xml file,

Tags: c#, visual-studio

r.cells[0].value will give an error under the word cells, visual studio states "datagridview does not contain a definition of cells"?   was wondering if anyyone knows how to fix the problem

```
        `DataSet ds = new DataSet();`
        `DataTable dt = new DataTable();`
        `dt.TableName = "UserDetails";`
        `dt.Columns.Add("Name");`
        `dt.Columns.Add("Email")`
        `dt.Columns.Add("Contact Number");`
        `ds.Tables.Add(dt);`


       `foreach(DataGridView r in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataRow row = ds.Tables["UserDetails"].NewRow();
            row["Name"] =r.Cells[0].Value;

        }`
```

Comment: `foreach(DataGridView r in dataGridView1.Rows)`  does that look correct?  `Rows` is a collection of `DataGridViewRows`.  Also, if you are really trying to write the data to an XML (as in the title) that capability is built into the DataSet. See `DataSet.WriteXml`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)`?